# Flatten XML after copy

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement to create a copy of the xml record based on a repeating field which I am able to do so, however I need the result to be flattened

I have tried to use variables and copying them to the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Hire>
        <xsl:for-each select="Hire/Record">
            <xsl:variable name="var_record" select="./* 
                             [not(name()='Sweldo')]" />
            <xsl:for-each select="Sweldo">
            <xsl:variable name="var_SWELDO" select="."> 
                            </xsl:variable>
            <Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$var_record" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$var_SWELDO" />
            </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Hire>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Hire>
 <Record>
 <XRefCode>XX</XRefCode>
 <EmployeeNumber>161</EmployeeNumber>
 <BirthDate>1985-04-09</BirthDate>
 <SocialSecurityNumber>XXXXXXX</SocialSecurityNumber>
 <FirstName>XX</FirstName>
 <LastName>XX</LastName>
 <MiddleName>D</MiddleName>
 <Sweldo>
  <sahod>ONE MILLION</sahod>
 </Sweldo>
 <Sweldo>
  <sahod>1 BILLION</sahod>
 </Sweldo>
 </Record>
 </Hire>
```

The output I am getting is

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Hire>
  <Record>
 <XRefCode>161</XRefCode>
 <EmployeeNumber>161</EmployeeNumber>
 <BirthDate>1985-04-09</BirthDate>
 <SocialSecurityNumber>999-81-9462</SocialSecurityNumber>
 <FirstName>XXX</FirstName>
 <LastName>XXXXX</LastName>
 <MiddleName>D</MiddleName>
 <Sweldo>
  <sahod>ONE MILLION</sahod>
 </Sweldo>
 </Record>
 <Record>
 <XRefCode>161</XRefCode>
 <EmployeeNumber>161</EmployeeNumber>
 <BirthDate>1985-04-09</BirthDate>
 <SocialSecurityNumber>999-81-9462</SocialSecurityNumber>
 <FirstName>XXX</FirstName>
 <LastName>XXXX</LastName>
 <MiddleName>D</MiddleName>
 <Sweldo>
  <sahod>1 BILLION</sahod>
 </Sweldo>
 </Record>
 </Hire>
```

However I need the following format

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Hire>
  <Record>
  <XRefCode>161</XRefCode>
  <EmployeeNumber>161</EmployeeNumber>
  <BirthDate>1985-04-09</BirthDate>
  <SocialSecurityNumber>999-81-9462</SocialSecurityNumber>
  <FirstName>XXXX</FirstName>
  <LastName>XXXXXX</LastName>
  <MiddleName>D</MiddleName>
  <sahod>ONE MILLION</sahod>
  </Record>
 <Record>
 <XRefCode>161</XRefCode>
 <EmployeeNumber>161</EmployeeNumber>
 <BirthDate>1985-04-09</BirthDate>
 <SocialSecurityNumber>999-81-9462</SocialSecurityNumber>
 <FirstName>XXXX</FirstName>
 <LastName>XXXX</LastName>
 <MiddleName>D</MiddleName>
 <sahod>1 BILLION</sahod>
 </Record>
 </Hire>
```

Is there a way to completely remove the  element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check and update following code:-

```
<xsl:for-each select="Sweldo">

      **change to**

<xsl:for-each select="Sweldo/sahod">
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to
 <xsl:for-each select="Hire/Record">
            <xsl:variable name="var_record" select="./* 
                             [not(name()='Sweldo')]" />
            <xsl:for-each select="Sweldo/sahod">
            <Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$var_record" />
   <newpay>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </newpay>
            </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>